# how can i use reference variable in php lambda function

Tags: php, lambda, reference

```
public function getAllByField(array &$condition)
{
    return $this->repository->scopeQuery(
        function ($query) use (&$condition) {
            return $query->where('status', '!=', '9')->whereRaw(
                array_reduce(
                    array_keys($condition), function ($carry, $k) use (&$condition) {
                        if(in_array('json', $item = $condition[$k])) {
                            $jsonColumns = explode('->', $item[0]);
                            unset($condition[$k]);

                            return  'JSON_VALUE('.$jsonColumns[0].',\'$.'.$jsonColumns[1].'\') '
                                    .$item[1].' '
                                    .(is_string($item[2])? '\''.$item[2].'\'':$item[2]);
                        }
                    }
                )
            );
        }
    )->findWhere($condition)->all();
}
```

i define the above method in this method `$condition` variable set by reference and in query unset some of value but when i use `$condition` in last line this change(`unset()`) not save!
how can i save changed `$condition`?

Comment: Did you tried to pass $condition variable by reference to your getAllByField function?

Comment: @DmitriyButeiko yes but not work!

Comment: Try to pass by reference everywhere in your code

Comment: @DmitriyButeiko can you explain more? how can i pass by reference?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that in your signature you use `array $condition` instead of `array &$condition` and thus all your references in the lambas are references to an initial copy. Here is a small example:

```
function removeTest(array &$condition)
{
    (function () use (&$condition) {
        if (isset($condition["test"])) {
            unset($condition["test"]);
        }
    })();
}

$arr = ["test" => "test", "test2" => "test2"];
removeTest($arr);
print_r($arr); // prints ["test2" => "test2"]
```

If you remove the initial & in the removeTest signature it doesn't matter that the lambdas use variables by reference since the first call will have made a copy and the original `$arr` is left untouched.

If you were to use objects instead it is always by reference:

```
function removeTest($condition)
{
    (function () use ($condition) {
        if (isset($condition->test)) {
            unset($condition->test);
        }
    })();
}

$obj = (object) ["test" => "test", "test2" => "test2"];
removeTest($obj);
print_r($obj); // prints stdClass Object("test2" => "test2")
```

Comment: @navidrajaie Then your problem is no longer in the code you have in your post but perhaps in the caller to `getAllByField`. Remember all it takes to make a copy is `$arr2 = $arr1`.